# dynamically set Atttribute for image url

Tags: javascript, html

Can you please do me a favour because I encounter the difficulities in setting attribute

dynamically to image tag .

What I want to do is that I want to set image "src" attribute dynamically depending on

user's gender(Male/Female). I seperate two different folders which contain images.(one for

male, one for female) as following.

[image]

in the index.html file

I wrote the code for input information for the browser as following

```
<div class="input-information">

      <select class="gender" name="">
          
          <option value="Mr">Mr</option>

          <option value="Ms">Ms</option>

      </select>

      <input type="text" class = "input-name" name="" value="" placeholder = "Type your Name">

      <button type="button" name="button">choose</button>

</div>
```

the browser show like this for those code;

[image]

What I want to make it happen is that if the user choose "Mr", the images will be chosen

from relevant folder which is "female" folder. if the user choose "Ms", the images will be

chosen from "male" folder. Which mean that men's piciturs for the ladies and lady's pictures

for the men.

To do so, in javascript file, I wrote the code like below:

```
let numberOfOptions = document.querySelectorAll("option").length;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (event){

  let randomNumber = Math.random() * 11;

  randomNumber = Math.floor(randomNumber) + 1;

  for(i=0; i< numberOfOptions; i++){

    let sex = document.querySelectorAll("option")[i].getAttribute("value");

    if(sex === "Mr"){
       document.querySelector(".soulmate").setAttribute("src","images/female/attress"+randomNumber+".PNG");
      
    }else if(sex === "Ms"){
       document.querySelector(".soulmate").setAttribute("src","images/male/actor"+randomNumber+".PNG");

    }else{

     console.log("error"); 
   }
  }
})
```

But, when I run the code, the browser always choose the pictures for the lady which are the

men's pictures eventhough I chosen "Mr" from dropdown menu.The girls's pictures doesn't

show at all which likly to be the variable "sex" is always set to the value of "Ms".

I don't know how to fix the code. So , Please direct me how to fix the code to get desire

result.

Thank you very much.

Aung

Comment: Your post is a little mixedup , butvtry loggong your output first. You are now checking al fields on the value, try adressing just the field you need ,or better add an onchange eventlistener on the mr/ms field and just set a variable, much cleaner

Comment: You should not use a click handler on each individual option, but one _change_ handler on the select field itself.

Comment: You are currently looping through _all_ the options inside your click handler, so you are _overwriting_ the src of your image element in each iteration. And since the _last_ option you are processing has the value `Ms`, you always get the corresponding result.